# How to convert varchar to datetime format in where clause while firing the query?

Tags: datetime

my query is ->

select * from table where creation_Date BETWEEN '"+fromDate+"' and '"+ToDate+"'"

- creation_Date  column is of DateTime format and from date and Todate in string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes it worked.Thank you so much. :) 
Here it is -                                                                            
select * from table where creation_ts BETWEEN (STR_TO_DATE('2012/05/31','%Y-%m-%d %H.%i.%s')) and (STR_TO_DATE('2012/05/31','%Y-%m-%d %H.%i.%s'))

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to mark the question as Resolved so that others can find the answer !